# About Google App Engine Socket API

Tags: google-app-engine, sockets

I'm calling a URL to get json data from another web site in my Google App Engine application. Then i received bellow message.

> The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has
>   been enabled in the admin console

So i decided to enable billing. but i have some question.

For [Mail API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail), we can send 100 messages per day for free. Like this are there any Free Default Limit for Socket API ?

How much should i pay for using Socket API ?

Should i pay per day or per minute ?

Can anyone explain how to setting daily budget and etc when enabling billing on google app engine ?

Comment: Not a coding question

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Sockets API is available in [beta](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/), so you need to take that into consideration that it could be subject to some changes.

In terms of the Quotas, it has been clearly defined over here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Sockets.

Additionally, keep in mind that that traffic from sockets is billed as outgoing bandwidth.